# nx is not invalidating the cache when TypeScript declaration files change in dependencies

Tags: typescript, nrwl-nx, lerna, nrwl, pnpm

I have a monorepo that uses Lerna with nx and PNPM workspaces. There are many packages that depend on each other. We use a custom build tool that uses TSC and Babel to type check and build our packages in one step, respectively. It seems like nx does not consider changes to TypeScript declaration files (*.d.ts) when determining whether a downstream package should be rebuilt. For example, if `package-b` depends on `package-a`, and some types in `package-a` change, nx still restores `package-b` from the cache. This is true even if those type changes in `package-a` cause type errors in `package-b`. Is there a way to make nx rebuild `package-b` when type declaration files change in `package-a`? Perhaps nx doesn't account for type declaration changes in the build output by default.

Here is an example of the type of change I make in `package-a` that I would expect to cause a rebuild in `package-b`. I start with a React component that has a `disabled` prop with type `boolean`.

```
// package-a

interface ButtonProps {
  disabled?: boolean;
}

export const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => <button {...props} />;

// package-b 

import { Button } from 'package-a';

const CustomButton = () => <Button disabled={true} />;
```

If I run `build` across the repo, change the type of `disabled` to `number`, then run `build` again, nx doesn't rerun the build in `package-b`, even though it has a new type error in my IDE.

```
// package-a
interface ButtonProps {
  disabled?: number;
}

export const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => <button {...props} />;

// package-b {
import { Button } from 'package-a';

const CustomButton = () => <Button disabled={true} />; // Type Error: Type boolean is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

nx shows the following message next to `package-b` in the terminal:

```bash
package-b:build  [existing outputs match the cache, left as is]
```

I confirmed that the type change is reflected in `Button.d.ts` in the build folder for `package-a`. When I change something that affect the JS output of the build for `package-a`, it rebuilds `package-b` as expected.

Here are my versions:

nx: 16.2.2

lerna: 6.6.2

pnpm: 7.27.0

Here is the relevant portion of my `nx.json` file.

```json
{
  "tasksRunnerOptions": {
    "default": {
      "runner": "nx/tasks-runners/default",
      "options": {
        "cacheableOperations": ["build"]
      }
    }
  },
  "namedInputs": {
    "default": ["{projectRoot}/**/*"],
    "buildScripts": ["{workspaceRoot}/build-scripts/**/*"],
    "ignoreTests": [
      "!{projectRoot}/**/__tests__/**/*",
      "!{projectRoot}/**/*.test.[jt]sx?",
      "!{projectRoot}/**/*.spec.js"
    ],
    "ignoreMarkdown": ["!{projectRoot}/**/*.md"]
  },
  "targetDefaults": {
    "build": {
      "inputs": ["default", "buildScripts", "ignoreMarkdown", "ignoreTests"],
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "outputs": ["{projectRoot}/build"]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding `"{projectRoot}/build/**/*.d.ts"` to my build outputs, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

```json
"build": {
  "inputs": ["default", "buildScripts", "ignoreMarkdown", "ignoreTests"],
  "dependsOn": ["^build"],
  "outputs": ["{projectRoot}/build", "{projectRoot}/build/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

I'm considering making a separate type checking script that will do all of the type checking, but I can't currently disable type checking in our custom build tool, so it will be a bit redundant. We've also come to expect type errors as part of our build step. It would be great if there is a way to get nx to rebuild downstream packages when type declarations change.

Comment: Now that I've written this all out, I'm realizing the solution may be to add the source files of downstream packages as inputs to the build step. For example, adding `"^default"` to the `"inputs"` array. It's still a bit weird to me that nx is ignoring changes to TS declaration files.

Comment: Did you run the nx graph to check the dependency between package-a and package-b?
Did you solve it already by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I ran `nx graph` to confirm the dependency. It seems to work for any changes that effect the JS build output, but not those that effect the TS declarations output. 

I tried to make a minimal monorepo using our build system, but I was unfortunately unable to reproduce the issue. I wonder if there is some particular quirk in our setup that I haven't been able to track down. That minimal monorepo is also using a more recent version of Nx, so perhaps if I downgrade I will be able to reproduce the issue. I had issues upgrading to the latest version in the real monorepo.

Comment: Any update on that one? I have a similar issue using scss files. I modify a parent project and the child one still uses the cache even if I have implicit dependency to the parent...

Comment: @JoG Adding the source files of dependencies in the repo works for us. For example, if package B depends on package A, adding the source code folder of package A as an input to package B. It's not ideal in that changes to source files may not always affect build output.